# Automatically move focus if username is correct. jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i have input field with `id='user'`
and i want to change focus automatically to input with `id='password'`

when username is correct, using jquery. ( `$("#password").focus();`)  What is the simplest way to do it?

Many thanks!

Comment: That's the simplest way to do you are having. What reason you felt that's not simple?

Comment: Please define `correct`.

Comment: do you wanna check whether the entered username is there in the database table?

Comment: correct is example "user". Right now i added window.setInterval function that checks every 0.5 seconds. and if username correct it changes focus to password.

Comment: @Farseer Looks like a really bad idea, e.g, for `user2`. You'd have better to forget about it

Comment: @Farseer very wierd functionality, why do you have it this way? most websites have just tabindex so that username > tab > password is possible.. and its pretty much standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the selected approach is somewhat weird (and obviously unsecured). However, it might be better to use `keyup` event instead of pinging the `#user` text field every 0.5 seconds:

```
$('#user').on('keyup', function() {
    if (this.value === 'user') {
        $('#password').focus();
    }
});
```